# How to programmatically select pan/zoom in pyqt/matplotlib navigation

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a pyqt4 matplotlib application and I would like the figure to start out (default) to the pan zoom mode when the application opens.  I can't find any example or clue from the documentation on how to do this programmatically.

Also along this same line how would I enable the shortcut keys in my application (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Colin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar issue and in my case I solved it by using `toolbar.zoom()`:

```
import pylab

plt.Figure()
thismanager = get_current_fig_manager()
thismanager.toolbar.zoom()
```

In that case the figure will appear with the zoom tool already selected

Comment: My setup as a pyqt4 application is a little different than what you describe but you got me on the right track.

Comment: The solution I ended up with was:`code`self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.map_canvas, None)  self.mpl_toolbar.pan()'code'

Comment: Thanks!  It's frustrating when something so simple can take so long to find.

Comment: If you're using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` , use this one liner `plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar.pan()` to default to pan