# Adding a toolbar to a MPL figure in PyQt4

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a very simple pyqt4 application that embeds a MatPlotLib figure.  I am embedding the matplotlib figure through the MatplotlibWidget and I created the interface through the QtDesigner along with [pyuic4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/designer.html).

I would like to provide the user access to the [toolbar for interactive navigation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/navigation_toolbar.html).  But, despite their nice example on GTK, I can't seem to get it to work for pyQt.  It mentions examples, but the [example for QT4 provided](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) does not include the toolbar.

I appreciate any help with this.

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133478/how-to-programmatically-select-pan-zoom-in-pyqt-matplotlib-navigation) is similar, but does not quite address what I need and I have not been able to adapt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no toolbar widget in QtDesigner, but you can add the toolbar by code:

Here is the example, the `plot_layout` is a `QVBoxLayout` designed by QtDesigner, and `plot_canvas` is the `MatplotlibWidget` widget.

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from plot_dialog2 import Ui_Form

class PlotDialog(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.navi_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.plot_canvas, self)
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.navi_toolbar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = PlotDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```