# Entering pan mode after embedding Matplotlib figure and toolbar into PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, embed, pysimplegui, pan

Is there a way to programmatically enter Matplotlib's pan mode, given that the figure is embedded into PySimpleGUI?
[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZRGC.png)

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of

```python
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.pan()
```

(which doesn't seem to work with PySimpleGUI, as
`fig.canvas.manager` is `None` in that case).

Here is a simple code to embed Matplotlib into PySimpleGUI with the toolbar:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk



"""----------------------------- matplotlib stuff -----------------------------"""
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
x_data = np.linspace(-42, 42, 300)
ax.plot(x_data, np.sin(x_data))



"""----------------------------- PySimpleGUI stuff -----------------------------"""
window_layout = [
    [sg.Canvas(key="-CANVAS_TOOLBAR-")],
    [sg.Canvas(key="-CANVAS_FIG-")]
]

window = sg.Window('Window', window_layout, resizable=True, finalize=True)



"""--------------------- embedding matplotlib into the GUI ---------------------"""
class Toolbar(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Toolbar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def draw_figure_w_toolbar(canvas_fig, canvas_toolbar, figure):
    figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas_fig)
    toolbar = Toolbar(figure_canvas_agg, canvas_toolbar)
    figure_canvas_agg.draw()
    toolbar.update()
    figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    return figure_canvas_agg

fig_agg = draw_figure_w_toolbar(window['-CANVAS_FIG-'].TKCanvas, window['-CANVAS_TOOLBAR-'].TKCanvas, fig)
# print(type(fig_agg))
# print(type(fig.canvas))



"""-------------------------- reading the GUI window --------------------------"""
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print("event", event, "\nvalues", values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "-ESCAPE-"):
        break

window.close()
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145965/zoom-capable-matplotlib-window-embedded-in-a-pysimplegui-window-tab), but I wish to use Matplotlib's toolbar.

Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133478/how-to-programmatically-select-pan-zoom-in-pyqt-matplotlib-navigation) doesn't work because `plt.get_current_fig_manager()` returns `None` in my case.

When printing `type(fig_agg)` from the code above, I get

```python
<class 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg'>
```

which is also the type of `fig.canvas`.

*By the way I thought about a trick to do it. Pressing <kbd>p</kbd> on the keyboard normally activates pan mode, so pressing the button programmatically does the trick! But that would be unethical cheating (:*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. In case it helps someone, the solution is simply

```
fig.canvas.toolbar.pan()
```

i.e. we remove `manager` from the original call mentioned above.